# Should I turn vermicompost?

Tags: vermicomposting

After adding plant matter to vermicompost, it kinda just sits there for a while, attracting fruit flies and growing mould.

Would it be better to try to turn the compost so that the new matter is at the bottom, covered from mould and fruit flies? How to do it without hurting the worms?

I am using [Urbalive vermicomposter](https://www.plastia.eu/en/low-worm-farm-urbalive-light-anthracite-29505p) which looks like this:

[image]

It has two layers, but the second one is empty so far. Maybe I should start using both?

Comment: What shape is your container? My proper vermicomposter is designed to be used in layers, and not turned, but can't have too much material added at one time. My rather cool deep compost bins have a significant amount of worm action, and benefit from turning.

Comment: @ChrisH I added a picture. It has two layers, but the second one is empty so far. Maybe we should start using both?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Summarising from the instructions that came with mine (a similar shape) you should add material in layers, first filling the bottom layer and only then moving on to the top.  It's quite easy to add too much, especially at first, and it may be getting too wet.  If used mainly for kitchen scraps it may also end up with too much nitrogen-rich material.  Adding a bit of newspaper can help - maybe a layer on top while things settle down, as it sounds like it's quite new.

At first they can be a little slow, and need a bit of compost or similar organic material to help them get started - with mine this was described as being something for the worms to live in until they process the vegetable matter you add.  Mine lives outside; I'm sceptical of the advice saying you can use them properly indoors except in a well-ventilated place.

Comment: You're rightfully sceptical about indoor use. I mean it doesn't smell at all, that's true, but the swarms of fruit flies are quite frustrating.

Comment: I get them round my little caddy in the summer